# Slow inserts for CoreData many-to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have two models, with a many-to-many relationship between them. The model A
starts in an empty state, while the model B has about 220k records (with a quite
big index, but this shouldn't affect, since this model is never updated).

The to-many from A->B is as follows:

- optional   => false
- transient  => false
- indexed    => true
- ordered    => true
- minCount   => 0
- maxCount   => NSIntegerMax
- deleteRule => NSCascadeDeleteRule

The to-many from B->A is as follows:

- optional   => true
- transient  => false
- indexed    => false
- ordered    => false
- minCount   => 0
- maxCount   => NSIntegerMax
- deleteRule => NSNullifyDeleteRule

And of course, each relationship is set as inverse of the other. The problem I'm
facing is the following: prior to create a new entity A, the app performs a
fetch request which gets about 2k records of the entity B. Then, the app sets
these records to the entity A about to be created, and then saves the context.
The problem is setting the nsorderedset of 2k records to the entity A instance
is taking 4 seconds more or less in an iPhone 4S with iOS 6.0.1, and saving the
context is taking another 4 seconds more or less, in the same device. That makes
8 seconds to create a new instance of model A.

I've tried enabling/disabling the indexed association property in model A, but
that didn't make such a difference. It's that heavy the task I'm trying to
achieve?

Making some tests, I've observed that most of the time lost setting the
nsorderedset to the entity A instance is because of the inverse relationship. I
made a quick test changing the many-to-many relationship to a to-many without
inverse relationship in the target model, and then the insert time went down to
half the time. Of course this breaks the many-to-many relationship. It was just
a quick test.

Am I missing something here? Since the app is saving the context just one time,
and not one time per each record B, it shouldn't take that long to save 2k
records, but I'm new to iPhone development, and maybe this task I'm performing
is too much for this kind of device.

Any hints would be greatly appreaciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ferdev,

Thank you for a well written question. It is clear you have thought carefully about your problem before asking for help. This helps everyone.

Core Data does not appear to use block operations when it saves. Hence, you are going to have performance issues there. The relationship setting though should be faster than you're seeing.(BTW, most of the performance issues are driven by the speed of flash memory. It is slow on iOS devices. Hence, prefetching to keep your MOC hot with your data is important. Bulk fetching is important.)

I make several observations:

Why is the A->B to-many relationship both indexed and ordered? The ordering will slow down your inserts. Does it also make sense to index a relationship?

Are you using the bulk relationship setters (`-add<Key>:`)?

Are you fetching all 2000 of your entity B records before you set them to the entity A instance?

Even though this doesn't affect your insert performance, why does the delete rule from A->B cascade? You write above entity B doesn't change.

Andrew

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your response. Answering your questions:

1. Yeah, indexing a relationship probably doesn't make any sense, so I'll remove it. But, I do need the ordered relationship.  The order of the B records are important.... Is there any other way to do this using CoreData?

2. No, because I can't assing an ordered set to a bulk setter. I don't know if this is a mistake I'm making, or if it's a known issue. I confess I haven't read further info about this.

3. Yeah, all b records are previously fetched... 

4. Does this rule remove also the b records? Or just the relationship info?

Comment: Ferdev, is insertion order the only way you organize these records? Or is there a field that represents the same thing which you can index? If so, then you should use that index and dispense with the ordered set in favor of the much faster `NSSet`. Item 2) See the answer with item 1. Item 4) Yes, a cascade delete will delete the records in B. Andrew

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better. The fetch is ordered (descently) using a numeric property of entity b. Once the fetch is made, all records are ordered using that field. Hence, I need an ordered relationship to be able to mantain that order. Anyway, I've just tried disabling the order attribute in the relationship, and the performance is more or less the same. I guess I'm doing something terribly wrong which is causing my performance problems. Thanks again!

Comment: Ferdev, If the items in B have an easy to recreate sort order, which it appears they do, then you do not need an ordered set. When you disabled the ordering, did you use the bulk `-add<Key>:` method? The next step is to create a simpler app for testing that simulates the A->B relationship. If it is still slow, then the problem is CD. If not, then it is your code. Andrew

Comment: I've changed the `entityA.products = orderedSet` to `entityA.setProducts(orderedSet)` and that has fixed the first bottleneck, apparently. The save action still takes ages, though. Looks like hardware limitation, as you said earlier, since in the simulator it only takes 0.2 secs to save the context, while in the iPhone is taking around 4-6 seconds for the very same data.

Comment: Ferdev, If you're happy with my answer, then please remember to turn the gray check mark green. Andrew